# Using Default Optional argument and recur together in Clojure

Tags: recursion, clojure, tail-call-optimization

I am able to set a default argument and do a regular recursion with it, but for some reason I cannot do with `recur` for tail optimization... I keep getting an `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: nth not supported on this type: Long` error.

For example, for a Tail Call Factorial, here is what works, but isn't optimized for tail call recursion and will fail for large recursion stacks.

```
(defn foo [n & [optional]]
   (if (= n 0) (or optional 1)
   (foo (dec n) (*' (or optional 1) n))))
```

And I call this by `(foo 3)`

And when I try this to get TCO, I get the unsupported operation error...

```
(defn foo [n & [optional]]
   (if (= n 0) (or optional 1)
   (recur (dec n) (*' (or optional 1) n))))
```

And I call this one the same way `(foo 3)`

Why is this difference causing an error? How exactly would I be able to do TCO with optional default arguments?

Thank you!

EDIT:

and when I try to take out the `(or optional 1)` in the recursion call and make it just `optional` , i get a null exception error... Which makes sense.

This also does not get fixed when I try to remove the `'` from `*'` in the recursion call

EDIT: I would also prefer to do this without `loop` as well

Answer (score 2):

It is [a known issue](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-283):

> Recur doesn't re-enter the function, it just goes back to the top (the vararging doesn't happen again) ... recur with a collection and you will be fine.

I personally feel it should either be mentioned in the `recur` docstring, or at least appear in the doc. Takes a bit of digging to understand what's happening (I had to check Clojure compiler source along with the compiled classes.)

Answer (score 1):

You can give a function multiple different arities. This might be what you're after?

```
(defn foo
  ([n]
    (foo n 1))
  ([n optional]
   (if (= n 0)
     (or optional 1)
     (recur (dec n) (*' (or optional 1) n)))))
```

I don't quite understand why there is an error, but recur wouldn't normally be used in a function with optional arguments.

**Edit**: after reading the other answer links, I understand the [problem](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-283) now. recur doesn't destructure the rest args like it does when you call the function. If you recur with a collection as the second arg, it will work, but it is probably still better to be explicit with two different arities:

```
(defn foo [n & [optional]]
  (if (= n 0)
    (or optional 1)
    (recur (dec n) [(*' (or optional 1) n)])))
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why is this difference causing an error?

- In short, it's trying to destructure a Long, which it can't
- Straight `foo` call

  - Takes n arguments
  - Automatically puts everything after the first argument (`n`) into a seq behind the scenes, which can be destructured
- `recur` call to `foo`

  - Takes exactly 2 arguments
  - First argument: `n`
  - Second argument: Something seqable with the rest of the arguments

> How exactly would I be able to do TCO with optional default arguments?

- Simply wrap the second argument to `recur` like so:

```
(defn foo [n & [optional]]
  (if (= n 0) (or optional 1)
  (recur (dec n) [(*' (or optional 1) n)])))

(foo 3)
;;=> 6
```

#### Recommendations

- Although he didn't answer your questions, @DanielCompton's recommendation is the way to go to completely avoid the problem in the first place in a clearer and more efficient way